# How can I solve this dependency problem installing Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, dependencies

I need to install the current version of Chrome on my 64-bit Intel box running Ubuntu 12.04. When I follow the steps at:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome

everything goes fine until the last command:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

When I run that last command, I get the output below. How can I resolve the "unmet dependencies"? Thanks so much for your help.

```
root@ECCServer:~# apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgnome2-0 : Depends: libgnome-2-0 (= 2.32.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
libgnome2-bin : Depends: libgnome-2-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically there is no way to really resolve that other than trying to force the install .. basically it needs libgnome-2.0 and you have 2.32.1-5

There is a good chance that if you forced it to install it would probably work with the 2.32 version and things would be fine but ... it is not guaranteed. Since it is added as a repository and you  don't have the .deb file .. you may be able to find the .deb file at `/var/cache/apt/archives/` if you can find it there then you can try

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends-version /var/cache/apt/archives/<name of chrome.deb>
```

This will turn dependency version problems into warnings and it should install but as I said .. no real guarantees that it will  function properly

Comment: That worked to get Chrome installed, John. Thank you very much. It does crash occasionally, though. Is there no way to update the old versions of the dependencies? I have the newest available for 12.04 via the Ubuntu repositories. When I've tried to manually install newer versions of those dependencies individually from other sources, I run into a rats nest of cascading unmet dependencies!

Comment: To be honest, I went by the error and found a workaround. I'm not sure if maybe chrome itself has updated so much that its having issues with the older versions. I"m not sure if you have a newer version of libgnome-2-0 or older .. or if it is installed at all ... you would have to check but from the way i read it and I may be wrong .. you have a newer version than what the installer was looking for and that was what was causing it to fail

Comment: John,  Now Ubuntu Software Center says:

Package dependencies cannot be resolved
...could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. ...could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Details:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
modemmanager: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.22-7 is to be installed
              Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.48.1-1 is to be installed

+ 14 more “Depends:...”
Ran “apt-get -f check”, with no change.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Dan